# Associating image files to dynamic $row objects on PHP

Tags: php, html, json, api, row

I'm trying to build something like http://www.coincap.io/ as a study project.
So far I managed to successfully build a table using the api at http://www.coincap.io/front

What I'm trying to do next is add an icon to the left of each object on `$row->long;`. Those icons would be hosted in a local folder, and they all have the same name as the `'long'` attribute (e.g. Bitcoin.png for "long":"Bitcoin").

Since it's a dynamic table and the objects change rows constantly, how can I add each icon to the corresponding 'long' object in a dynamic way?

```
<table><head><style>
td {text-align: right; display:float; }
</style></head><table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Mkt Cap</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
            <th>Supply</th>
            <th>24h(%)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php function compare($a, $b) {
            return intval($a->position24) - intval($b->position24);
        } 

        $json = file_get_contents('http://www.coincap.io/front');
        $data = json_decode($json);
        usort($data, 'compare'); 
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row->position24; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->long; ?></td>
            <td><?= number_format($row->price, 4); ?><\td>
            <td><?= number_format($row->mktcap, 2); ?><\td>
            <td><?= number_format($row->volume, 2); ?><\td>
            <td><?= number_format($row->supply, 2); ?><\td>
            <td><?= $row->cap24hrChange; ?><\td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting all images set to the placeholder.

```
<td><img src="/wp-content/uploads/icons/<?= file_exists('/wp-content/uploads/icons/' . $row->long . '.png') ? $row->long : 'unknown'; ?>.png" ></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add them in another column in your table.

First, add a header for it:

```
<tr>
    <th></th><!-- Doesn't have to be empty -->
    <th>#Rank</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Mkt Cap</th>
    <th>Volume</th>
    <th>Supply</th>
    <th>24h(%)</th>
</tr>
```

Then where you're looping through the results, add the image column:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><img src="images/<?= file_exists('/path/to/images/' . $row->long . '.png') ? $row->long : 'unknown'; ?>.png" alt="<?= $row->long; ?>"></td>
    <td><?= $row->position24; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row->long; ?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($row->price, 4); ?><\td>
    <td><?= number_format($row->mktcap, 2); ?><\td>
    <td><?= number_format($row->volume, 2); ?><\td>
    <td><?= number_format($row->supply, 2); ?><\td>
    <td><?= $row->cap24hrChange; ?><\td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Beautiful! I realized that some of the objects won't have a corresponding image eventually. How can I set a default image to be exibited in those cases?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a `file_exists()` check to catch those situations.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting all images set to default:  `<td><img src="/wp-content/uploads/icons/<?= file_exists('/wp-content/uploads/icons/' . $row->long . '.png') ? $row->long : 'unknown'; ?>.png" ></td>`

Comment: You did change `/path/to/images/` to the actual (absolute) path on the server, right? ;-)

Comment: That's not the absolute path, but a relative path. `file_exists()` works on OS level, so you'll need to use the full path (e.g. `'/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/icons/'`) or use one of the PHP path constants (e.g. `__DIR__ . '/../wp-content/uploads/icons/'` where `__DIR__` refers to the folder your template file is in, so you might need to get creative with the number of `../`)

Comment: Feeling really stoopid right now. I fixed the paths and it's working like a charm. Many thanks :)